# regeneratorRuntime error with new au-cli

Tags: babeljs, aurelia

I'm trying to convert an existing project to use the aurelia cli and I've encountered an old problem. I'm getting a regeneratorRuntime is not defined error. I fixed this a while back in a previous version but either my memory is hazy or that knowledge doesn't apply to this version. Can anyone point me to a source or give me some advice on how to fix this with this version?

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me was to add the babel-polyfill to the vendor-bundle section of `aurelia-project/aurelia.json`, like this:

```
"name": "vendor-bundle.js",
"prepend": [
    "node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js",
    "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
    "scripts/require.js"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it.  Once you get how the aurelia.json file works, it's not to difficult.  Add this to aurelia.json:

          `{
            "name": "regenerator-runtime",
            "path": "../node_modules/regenerator-runtime",
            "main": "runtime-module"
          }`

Then add this to main.js:
```
    import regeneratorRuntime from 'regenerator-runtime';

```
window.regeneratorRuntime = regeneratorRuntime;
```

```

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Comment: There's a comment in main.js:
`// If you don't use async/await, you can remove regenerator-runtime.`
That fixes the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

A hackish solution for now (thanks to Roland Quast @rquast from https://gitter.im/aurelia):

You need to install and require babel-polyfill in your main.js file explicitly:

`require('node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js')`